# MongoDB find in nested array of documents

Tags: mongodb

How to find documents where multi nested array of documents match value.

house->rooms->beds->type: (string)'any_value'

rooms is an array of objects and beds is an array of objects.

Do not work

```
{rooms: {$elemMatch: {beds: {$elemMatch: {type: {$exists: true}}}}}}
{rooms: {$elemMatch:  {beds: {$elemMatch: {type: 'single_bed'}}}}}
```

This shows me all houses where have rooms with beds.

```
{rooms: {$elemMatch: {beds: {$exists: true}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an unsorted array.

```
rooms[0][beds][1][type]
rooms[0][beds][0][type]
```

This is stored as an object. If I re-sort the fields and specify `beds[0]` then `beds[1]`, it is saved as an array.